# Adding API to allow customers to create an object and receive response in an existing rails app

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I'm having a routing problem when it comes to creating a url where customers can POST an object and get a JSON response with information about the object. I have an existing rails app, and I'm adding an API to allow customers to create a Point object by passing in a latitude and longitude. I have created a controller in `api/v1/points_controller.rb`.

In the routes file, I have

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :points, only: [:create]
  end
end
```

when I test it out with `localhost:3000/api/v1/points/create?lat=xx.xxx&lng=xx.xxxx` it doesn't work and gets rerouted to the home page based on some catchall routing when the page doesn't exist.

If I add a route `get 'api/v1/points/create'` then the above url works perfectly, but this isn't very RESTful and I think a small change would probably fix the issue.

My controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class PointsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  
      def new
        p = Point.new
      end

      def create
        if params[:lat].present?
          p = Point.create(lat: params[:lat], lng: params[:lng])
          response = p.find_school
        elsif params[:number].present?
          number = params[:number]
          cp = params[:cp]
          street = params[:street]
          suffix = params[:suffix]
          address = "#{number} #{cp} #{street} #{suffix}"
          address = address.squeeze(" ")
          # address = address.gsub!(/\+{1,}/,"+") 
          city = params[:city]
          state = params[:state]
          zip = params[:zip]
          p = Point.create(cp: cp, number: number, street: street, suffix: suffix, address: address, city: city, state: state, zip: zip)
          p.geocode
          response = p.find_school
        end
    
        render json: response
 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? What was the reason of it? You have defined a POST route (using `:create`) yet you are trying to access it with GET based on your example. That should not work, anyway, and was maybe the reason why you were redirected with some catch-all rule.

Comment: I haven't solved this issue. The only way I can get it to work is to create the GET route.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds two-fold: what HTTP methods Rails expects for your defined routes, and how to test them.

**Rails `create` routes and HTTP methods**

In short, when you define a `create` route in Rails, it is expected to be requested using the HTTP method POST.

In your terminal, you can see the defined routes and what HTTP methods they expect to be used with by invoking

```
bin/rails routes
```

The output should look something like this (without the line numbers):

```
1          Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
2   api_v1_points POST /api/v1/points(.:format) api/v1/points#create
```

The first line has the column headers. The second and any consecutive lines show the details of each route. The interesting columns for your question are *Verb*, *URI Pattern*, and *Controller#Action*.

The *Verb* column tells you that it expects an HTTP POST request. The *Controller#Action* column tells you which controller and which action within the controller is going to handle the request that comes to your web app at the URL path shown in the *URI Pattern* column.

In your case, any HTTP POST request to http://localhost:3000/api/v1/points should be handled by the `Api::V1::PointsController` and its `create` action. It doesn't accept HTTP GET requests because you don't have any such routes defined for your `PointsController`.

Note how the *URI Pattern* (URL path) for your route in the output does not end with `/create`. This is because Rails by default expects a POST request to be sent to the path of the controller name and not of the controller action name: `/points` vs. `/points/create`, in your case.

The URL http://localhost:3000/api/v1/points/create?lat=xx.xxx&lng=xx.xxxx represents an HTTP GET request. To make it work for your app, it should be http://localhost:3000/api/v1/points and it should send `lat=xx.xxx&lng=xx.xxxx` as the request body. More about the latter below.

**Testing POST requests**

You didn't specify exactly how you tried to test the route but based on your post I assume that you were using the browser because you mentioned it works when you define the route as GET.

In short, you cannot test HTTP POST requests directly with your browser. Your browser sends HTTP GET requests, by default, and your app expects an HTTP POST, as I've explained above.

In contrast to GET requests that can send parameters in the URL as query parameters, POST requests need the POST data defined in the request body that you cannot access using only your browser's address bar.

To send POST requests to your app, I would recommend installing a command-line tool such as [HTTPie](https://httpie.io/docs/cli/main-features), for example. Many other tools exist, such as [curl](https://curl.se/download.html) for the command line, or [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/download) with a GUI and that makes testing more complex request cases easier. There are also browser extensions that allow you to send HTTP POST requests but I have never used them so I can't help you with them.

With HTTPie, you could make a POST request to your app invoking the following in your terminal

```
http POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/points lat=12.345 lng=123.456
```

Using the right tool to test HTTP requests is important and makes your life so much easier.